Understanding pressure in terms of force
I find it quite difficult to visualize and understand pressure from a physical point of view instead of mathematically.
We define pressure as force exerted perpendicularly per unit area. But what about the case, when a large number of forces are applied. As for example $3$ forces from the right and $2$ forces from the left. Let's assume for simplicity that all of them are of equal magnitude (though it isn't always in real scenario).
So, is pressure then the resultant force which is $1$ unit from the right per unit area?
Basically is pressure the net normal force on a surface per unit area?
Also this definition seems to give the intuition that pressure comes from force, so if there is no force, there is no pressure. But even if equal opposite forces act, we do feel pressure. So I don't understand this dilemma. Is pressure then force independent?
Above all I want to understand how physicists think of pressure and how it should be thought of. It will be very helpful if explained in newtonian point of view.

"Basically is pressure the net normal force on a surface per unit area?" I don't think we use the word 'pressure' like this. If the pressure of the air in an 'empty' bottle is atmospheric we wouldn't say that there is zero pressure on its walls, just because there is the same pressure inside as outside, so equal and opposite normal forces on a given area of wall.

It is only useful to think in terms of pressure when there is a force that is distributed over a given area. In this case, if we know the total (perpendicular) force $F$ and the area $A$ it is distributed over then the average pressure exerted by the force is $P=\frac F A$. More often we know the pressure $P$ and the area $A$, so we can calculate the total perpendicular force $F = PA$.
If we have an (ideal) point force acting on an (ideal) rigid object then the force exerts a notionally "infinite" pressure at the point where it is applied, and zero pressure elsewhere. In this case, thinking in terms of pressure is not useful.

I am very dumb but I still don't find the answer to my question,I want to know if the net force per unit area is right.

In your example you don't say whether the forces are point forces or distributed forces. If they are distributed forces you don't say what area they are distributed over. You can only add pressures if there is some overlap in the areas over which the pressures are applied - you certainly cannot add pressures if they are applied to different faces of an object. So your example doesn't have enough detail for a definite answer.

Often pressure comes from air or water pressing on an object. In that case it is uniform on all sides.
On a microscopic scale, lots of molecules are bouncing off the object. Each one exerts a momentary force like a tiny hammer blow. It only feels smooth if you look at a large enough area that you can average. Over a square millimeter, there are so many atoms that at every instant many molecules are in the process of delivering a hammer blow. The individual blows are too small to feel. The cumulative effect is a continual force.
If you have a closed container with a vacuum inside, the pressure is only on the outside. It takes really strong walls to keep from being crushed.
If you have an open container, you have equal forces on the outside and inside. The walls are squeezed between opposing forces, but solids are strong enough to hold up. The equal forces do not push the walls in one direction or bend them.

Thank you for answering,but can we say pressure is net force per unit area as the example I gave in my post?

The example of air pressure is a good one. You say that "even if equal opposite forces act, we do feel pressure," but are you sure? After all, atmospheric pressure at sea level is about 100 kPa acting everywhere on your body. Do you feel that in your ears? I don't, because there's a balancing pressure from the inside. Balancing forces cancel, and there's no resulting acceleration to measure.

Suppose we are pressing our hands against each other,won't we feel pressure in our palm?

Yes left hand exerts force on right hand, right hand on left, to every force a counterforce, same for every pressure.

Happy new year. I like this question because while studying Hydrostatics myself, I realise how intigruing it is. So always clear off doubts from this chapter.
Pressure acting on a surface is given by net normal force per unit area??
As everyone is saying, pressure has not always to do with a surface only. It can involved a 3d space too. Think of this image: There is a closed room with 2 pistons on opposite windows, which are thus movable by pressure. Now you push the right window from outside with a force F.

The pressure created on outer surface is F/A. A is the window area.
Pascal's Law will tell you that the piston window of same area A on the other side will adjust itself so that the window explodes out of the room, until you stop it by applying F force from opposite side. The moment you do this, the first window stops sliding due to its own force. Why? Because the air pressure causes it to.

Tell me if you have a problem in understanding this, ask that later. First assume that this is really true. That assumed, now answer the question: what is the pressure acting on the window surface? F. But what is the net force acting on the window surface? The surface is actually several particles, which can be otheriwse be taken as 1 particle to apply Newton's Laws. Then, that particle is at rest. Net force is zero, but you cannot say pressure is zero. Pressure remains = F/A on the outer as well as inner surfaces of each window.
This is a limitation of your definition. My favoured definition: Thrust per unit area. (Lol but it is is enough for middle school and matriculation, and does not have that limitation). You may ask how this is relevant to air pressure. But fluid pressure is also defined wrt a certain depth from its upper free surface, i.e., it's the pressure on the cross-sectional plane area at that height (which is rho.g.h). Thus relevant.
This was almost the best possible thought process I could think of. If doubts remain, you can ask.
